# How to use AJAX - JSON to keep a data updated in JSP?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsp

I've looked and searched for hours and I couldn't find anything easy to understand. And I've to make an easy stuff.

So, I've a java class that has a map of "Service" objects with an int variable "lastCustomer".
This value change, how can I keep the updated data in my "display" page (without refreshing it)?

Supposed to use AJAX, Javascript and all this stuff, but don't know how.

**EDIT:**

OK, maybe I moved on. still stucked on the "parsing". For now I've written a servlet that takes the datas and print all the stuff in the pages with "/display/something". Now, how can I access through jQuery to it?

Basically I've a list of object (very object has a dynamic value).
I've to print the object and keep updated the value.

By the way, the JSON string provide me from the servlet doesn't update itself, it needs a refresh. I think I'm missing something basics.

Some code:

```
    @WebServlet("/JsonServices")
public class JsonServices extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {


        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(myClass.services());

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().println(json); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Just have a look at some AJAX tutorial. There are more than enough out there or here on SO. I would advise you to take a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com) as this is by far the easiest library to use for AJAX.

Comment: Your current problem is not clear. Is it ajax polling? Or is it parsing the received JSON? The latter actually belongs in a different question.

Comment: I think both. The first problem would be having the data updated: the servlet sends me the JSON string when I refresh the page, how can I have the new datas without refreshing?

After that I've my JSON string. And the problem would be how to use the data printed on the page..

[I think should be easy using them: gson.fromJson(datas) and that's the object]

Answer (score 2):

actually you need a long polling solution. it will trigger you when something change.
but you can do smiliar thing with ajax of course.

```
 function refresData(){
      $.ajax({
      url: "serverurl",
      type: "GET"
      success: function(data){
        //it will be your json or xml
      }
    });
   }

var refreshInterval = setInterval(refreshData, 30 * 1000);//30 seconds
refreshData();
```